# How can I make Aruba use a different ENV["HOME"]?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aruba

From [the docs](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba#configuration):

> Per default Aruba will create a directory tmp/aruba where it performs its file operations.

However, my application uses `ENV["HOME"]` to create and read a file (`~/.foorc`), so I need Aruba to use a fake `ENV["HOME"]`.

Do I need to set it in some support-file, or is there a way to tell Aruba to its `tmp/aruba` for files in `ENV["HOME"]`?

Here is an excerpt of my code that I am testing (obviously I am testing this with Cucumber/Aruba on a much higher level, but the usage of ENV["HOME"] is what is important here.):

```
def initialize config_path = ""
  if config_path.empty?
    @config_path = File.join ENV["HOME"], ".todotxt.cfg"
  else
    @config_path = config_path
  end

  if file_exists?
    super @config_path
    validate
  end
end

def file_exists?
  File.exists? @config_path
end

#....
  ask_to_create unless @config.file_exists?
#...
```

The Specification:

```
Scenario: todotxt
  Given an empty installation
  When I run `todotxt`
  Then it should pass with:
    """
    Should I create a sample config file? [Y/n]
    """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the implementation in Aruba itself, I could craft something very similar:

File *features/support/aruba.rb*, is autoloaded by cucumber and implements the `Around` hook:

```
# Temporarily enforce an isolated, fake, homedir.
around do |scenario, block|
  @__aruba_original_home = ENV["HOME"]
  ENV["HOME"] = File.expand_path(File.join("tmp", "aruba"))
  block.call
  ENV["HOME"] = @__aruba_original_home
end
```

From now on, a directory *tmp/aruba* is used as $HOME.

Note that in aruba, this temporary path is configurable, and that above code does not take that into consideration. It will break when the tmp path is configured elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Aruba offers [a step for just that](http://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/aruba/docs/environment/mock-the-home-variable):

`Given a mocked home directory`